# Rotate an image in java

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, bufferedimage, affinetransform

I am looking to rotate an image. I have a `JInternalFrame` which contains a `JLabel`. The label contains the image. After the image has been rotated, I need to resize the internal frame. The code I have currently rotates the image, but there is black around the edges of the image and it is off centered. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
public void rotateIcon(int angle)
{
        int w = theLabel.getIcon().getIconWidth();
        int h = theLabel.getIcon().getIconHeight();
        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;  // other options, see api

        BufferedImage DaImage = new BufferedImage(h, w, type);
        Graphics2D g2 = DaImage.createGraphics();

        double x = (h - w)/2.0;
        double y = (w - h)/2.0;
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);

        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), w/2.0, h/2.0);
        g2.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getData()).getImage(), at, theLabel);
        g2.dispose();

        theLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(DaImage));
        this.setSize(DaImage.getWidth(),DaImage.getHeight()); //resize the frame
}
```

Comment: In general, rotating an image changes the width and height (relative to X and Y axes). I'd guess this is contributing to it being "off centered." I've had to solve this by calculating the new size and accounting for it. As for the black edges, this is a pretty common case where the the rotating function isn't working with an alpha channel. Maybe this will help for the positioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056338/calculating-the-center-of-rotation-after-translation

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420651

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to be using trigonometry to determine the correct width/height, using transparency to prevent the black area, and I think the Transform is wrong, which is making it off center.

Try this:

```
public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage image, double angle) {
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
    int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
    int neww = (int)Math.floor(w*cos+h*sin), newh = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration();
    BufferedImage result = gc.createCompatibleImage(neww, newh, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
    g.translate((neww - w) / 2, (newh - h) / 2);
    g.rotate(angle, w / 2, h / 2);
    g.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
    g.dispose();
    return result;
}

private static GraphicsConfiguration getDefaultConfiguration() {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    return gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
}
```

from http://flyingdogz.wordpress.com/2008/02/11/image-rotate-in-java-2-easier-to-use/

Comment: This is really cool. I am having one issue with it though. My image only needs to rotate 90 degrees. at a time. If I pass in 90 for angle, it will actually rotate more than 90 degrees

Comment: This is using radians, so just use Math.toRadians(degree) first.

Comment: can we get rid of the screen device dependence?

Answer (score 5):

You could try using a [Rotated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/).

Comment: Thanks, I am going to have to look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a previous example, but actually working with recent JDKs and in headless mode:

```
public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage image, double angle) {
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
    int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
    int neww = (int)Math.floor(w*cos+h*sin), newh = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);
    BufferedImage result = deepCopy(image, false);
    Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
    g.translate((neww - w) / 2, (newh - h) / 2);
    g.rotate(angle, w / 2, h / 2);
    g.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
    g.dispose();
    return result;
}

public static BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage bi, boolean copyPixels) {
    ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
    boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = bi.getRaster().createCompatibleWritableRaster();
    if (copyPixels) {
        bi.copyData(raster);
    }
    return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you change:

`BufferedImage DaImage = new BufferedImage(height, width, type);`

to:

`BufferedImage DaImage = new BufferedImage(**width, height**, type);`?

Comment: Yea, I switched those back and forth, still no success.