# rotating an image 90 degrees in java

Tags: java, image, image-rotation

I have managed to rotate an image `180 degrees` but wish to rotate it `90 degrees` `clockwise` can someone edit my code so that it does this with explanation. Thanks.

```
 private void rotateClockwise()
    {
        if(currentImage != null){
            int width = currentImage.getWidth();
            int height = currentImage.getHeight();
            OFImage newImage = new OFImage(width, height);
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    newImage.setPixel( x, height-y-1, currentImage.getPixel(x, y));
                }
        }
            currentImage = newImage;
            imagePanel.setImage(currentImage);
            frame.pack();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Try to think what happens with each quarter of the image when you rotate it. I think that should be one good approach. Solve each quarter individually.

Comment: [example](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/69182-java-image-rotation/)

Comment: Thanks for the example Vignesh Vino. I managed to get it working much appreciated.

Comment: You need to swap x,y.  I'd put this as an answer but can't. OFImage newImage = new OFImage(height, width); newImage.setPixel(height-1-y, x, currentImage.getPixel(x, y));

Answer (score 13):

Use this method.

```
/**
 * Rotates an image. Actually rotates a new copy of the image.
 * 
 * @param img The image to be rotated
 * @param angle The angle in degrees
 * @return The rotated image
 */
public static Image rotate(Image img, double angle)
{
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))),
           cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));

    int w = img.getWidth(null), h = img.getHeight(null);

    int neww = (int) Math.floor(w*cos + h*sin),
        newh = (int) Math.floor(h*cos + w*sin);

    BufferedImage bimg = toBufferedImage(getEmptyImage(neww, newh));
    Graphics2D g = bimg.createGraphics();

    g.translate((neww-w)/2, (newh-h)/2);
    g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), w/2, h/2);
    g.drawRenderedImage(toBufferedImage(img), null);
    g.dispose();

    return toImage(bimg);
}
```

taken from my [ImageTool](https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/util/ImageTool.java) class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: why did you copy the image , does it not accomplish by applying 90 degree rotated affine transform while drawing ? please clarify.

Comment: @Mihir That's a requirement for my game. This class is from my game engine so I used that. You can use anything you like.

Comment: I actually had to create a new buffered image. Otherwise, I'm getting an unexpected results.

Comment: As I understand it this code rotates clockwise but how do I rotate it counter clockwise?

Comment: @TimothyPersoon Use negative angles for anti clockwise rotation.

Comment: Damn, didn't expect it to be that simple. I have another issue though. I need to put a sleep of 9 seconds in the code because otherwise it looks like it doesn't clear it's cache rightaway. My image element is the width & height of the newly rotated dimensions but the image itself is not rotated, see http://imgur.com/cWr9WZc Do you have any idea what causes this?

Comment: @TimothyPersoon Search for existing questions or create a new question. This is not the place to ask about the issue of caches.

Comment: Yeah I thought so but it is working with your code so I thought maybe you had the same problems. Caching is just a guess, but I will post a new question

Comment: You don't need to introduce transcendental functions to achieve rotaion. You can rotate simply by multiplication like in complex numbers.
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=njwildberger+rotation

Comment: @Lukas Can you explain in detail? I do know Quaternions are useful for representing rotations, and I do use them. However they are more useful in 3D space, and also in real-time calculations. For most 2D games, this is sufficient.

Comment: Why use the heavy trig stuff when the rotation is 90 degrees? A much simpler solution is found here: https://coderanch.com/t/485958/java/Rotating-buffered-image

Comment: @PerLindberg That's true, but the thing is that I've copied this from my project, and my requirement is to rotate at arbitrary angles.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate%28double%29 aswell as this post [Rotate an image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156518/rotate-an-image-in-java)