# Retrieve new width and height of BufferedImage bounds after a AffineTransform.rotate()

Tags: java, rotation, bufferedimage, bounds, affinetransform

I'm working on a type of image editor which includes snapping to other elements as a feature. The snapping works by using the image width and height.

However, after an AffineTransform.rotate() the image width and height are no longer the actual bounds of the rendered image and thus the snapping fails.

What's the best way of determining the width and height of the rectangular area that encompasses the rotated image?

Comment: This question seems like it was asked in the last day or so.  Was that you?

Comment: <friggin iPad> ... sorry, meant [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156518/rotate-an-image-in-java) (3rd time lucky...where's bed again?  Better check google-maps...)

Comment: Try `affineTransform.createTransformedShape(new Rectangle(width, height)).getBounds()`

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is the first time I've asked a question on stackoverflow :) I did do a search for similar questions but couldn't find an appropriate one.

Comment: @johnchen902 Ok, that suggestion does work but I need to maintain a `float` level of accuracy and `Rectangle` only accepts `int`s. Any ideas?

Comment: `affineTransform.createTransformedShape(new Rectangle2D.Double(width, height)).getBounds2D()`

Comment: @johnchen902 Ok, that works perfectly :) If you submit it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `int`:

```
affineTransform.createTransformedShape(new Rectangle(width, height))
        .getBounds();
```

For `double`:

```
affineTransform.createTransformedShape(
        new Rectangle2D.Double(width, height)).getBounds2D();
```