# Java - Method that resizes, rotates and draws a image after arguments

Tags: java, image, rotation, resize, draw

im trying to make a method in java that will resize rotate and draw a image after given arguments.
It does not work tho. Idk how? Btw is it posible to do this with the normal Graphic class and not Graphic2D ? Thanks!

```
    public void drawResizedAndRotatedImage(Image image, Graphics g, int x, int y, int sizeX, int sizeY, double degrees){
        //Resize
        BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(sizeX, sizeY, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Graphics g2 = (Graphics)im.getGraphics();

        //Rotate
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageIcon.getIconWidth(), imageIcon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), imageIcon.getIconWidth() / 2, imageIcon.getIconHeight() / 2);

        //Draw
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, sizeX, sizeY, null);
    }
```

Comment: *"is it posible to do this with the normal Graphic class and not Graphic2D ?"* - Have a look at the [JavaDocs for `Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) and tell us

Comment: Well i have looked there, but i couldent find anything.

Comment: Looks like you found your answer to that question then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you create a `BufferedImage` and grab it's `Graphics` context...

```
BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(sizeX, sizeY, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
Graphics g2 = (Graphics)im.getGraphics();
```

And do nothing with it...

You then create a second `BufferedImage`, grab it's `Graphics` context, set it's rotational context and paint nothing to it...

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageIcon.getIconWidth(), imageIcon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)bufferedImage.getGraphics();
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), imageIcon.getIconWidth() / 2, imageIcon.getIconHeight() / 2);
```

You then paint the original image to the supplied `Graphics` context...

```
g.drawImage(image, x, y, sizeX, sizeY, null);
```

Having achieved nothing at all...

I think you need to start by taking a read through [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) to get some grounding on the basics...

Transformations are compounding, they also only effect whatever is painted to the `Graphics` context AFTER they have been applied.

The simplest approach would actually be to use a `AffineTransform`

```
double scaleWidth = (double)sizeX / (double)image.getWidth(this);
double scaleHeight = (double)sizeY / (double)image.getHeight(this);
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(sizeX, sizeY, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), image.getWidth(this) / 2d, image.getHeight(this) / 2d);
g2d.setTransform(at);
g2d.drawImage(image, sizeX / 2, sizeY / 2, null);
g2d.dispose();

// And finally, the result...
g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
```

For example...

[image: Pony]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestImage();
    }

    public TestImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage original;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                original = ImageIO.read(new File("Your image here"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public Image scaleAndRotate(Image image, int sizeX, int sizeY, double degrees) {

            double scaleWidth = (double)sizeX / (double)image.getWidth(this);
            double scaleHeight = (double)sizeY / (double)image.getHeight(this);
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(sizeX, sizeY, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.scale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            at.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), image.getWidth(this) / 2d, image.getHeight(this) / 2d);
            g2d.setTransform(at);
            g2d.drawImage(image, sizeX / 2, sizeY / 2, null);
            g2d.dispose();

            return img;

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int scaleWidth = getWidth() / 2;
            int scaleHeight = getHeight() / 2;

            Image img = scaleAndRotate(original, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, 45.0);
            int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth(this)) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight()- img.getHeight(this)) / 2;

            g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

You may also like to take a read through...

- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)
- [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

For discussions about scaling algorithms and techniques

You should also know that the size of an image when it rotates also changes, have a look at (one of my favourite answers to refer to) [Rotate an image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156518/rotate-an-image-in-java) for more details about how to calculate the resulting image size of a rotated image...

Comment: @Oliver I'm sorry you feel that way, but rather than dumping a wall of code on you and expecting you to figure out how it works, I felt it was important to point out to why your code wasn't working and offer a solution so you could see the difference in the way they work.  I also feel that it's a good idea to provide you with the tools to help yourself, so you can further understand the solution and solve issues you might have on your own.

Comment: For some reason this doesent work. g.drawOval and stuff like that works but not this.... wired. But i think ill just go back to rotating the images in paint. And thanks. :)

Comment: Also i tryed to copy your class and run it. Got a error. wiered

Comment: You should get an error, you need to supply a fails image where it says, "Your image here" ;)