# Combining RotateTransform and TranslateTransform

Tags: c#, wpf, transform, rotatetransform

I am using the Thumb class to let the user drag and drop an image across a canvas. When the right button gets pressed, i want the user to be able to rotate the image. The rotation is based around the center of the image. I have the following XAML Code

```
<Grid>

    <Canvas Background="Red" Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="canvas" 
        PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="Canvas_MouseUp" 
        PreviewMouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove">

        <UserControl MouseRightButtonDown="Canvas_MouseDown" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

            <Thumb Name="myRoot" DragDelta="myRoot_DragDelta">
                <Thumb.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>

                            <Image Source="/WpfApplication1;component/someImage.png" />

                            <Rectangle Stroke="#FF0061CE" StrokeThickness="1" Width="230" Height="250" />

                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Thumb.Template>
            </Thumb>

            <UserControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" />
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </UserControl.RenderTransform>
        </UserControl>

    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

And this code behind

```
    bool isMouseDown = false;
    Point pos;
    double lastAngle = 0;

    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDown = true;
        lastAngle = rotateTransform.Angle;
        pos = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
    }   

    private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDown = false;
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isMouseDown) return;

        var curPos = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
        rotateTransform.Angle = lastAngle + (pos.Y - curPos.Y);
    }

    private void myRoot_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        translateTransform.X += e.HorizontalChange;
        translateTransform.Y += e.VerticalChange; 
    }
```

It works if i only drag and drop the image around the screen and rotate the image a small amount (50 degrees in any direction seems ok). However manipulating it more than that and the image starts move around the screen unpredictibly.

I have tried moving the transformations to different controls, so to not to mix them up but have not received an acceptable result.

How can i get my code to behave like i want?

UPDATE: This is driving my crazy. I have changed the code and XAML to use a MatrixTransformation instead

```
    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isMouseDown) return;

        var curPos = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);

        angle = (lastAngle + (pos.Y - curPos.Y)) % 360;

        UpdateMatrixTransform();
    }

    private void myRoot_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        posX += e.HorizontalChange;
        posY += e.VerticalChange;  

        UpdateMatrixTransform();
    }

    void UpdateMatrixTransform()
    {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();


        m.Rotate(angle);

        m.OffsetX = posX;
        m.OffsetY = posY;

        matrixT.Matrix = m;
    }
```

In my mind, this should work: First, rotate the graphic than move it to the offset. It does not work like i expect it to. It rotates the image, but than moves it strangely in spiral fashion outwards if i keep moving the mouse. No matter what i do, and in what order i execute my transformations, it wont work.

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056338/calculating-the-center-of-rotation-after-translation/2063125#2063125

Comment: @Gilad I am not sure how this link is helping me, could you maybe give a hint?

Comment: Try swapping the order of the transforms.  It should Translate first, Rotate second.

Comment: @Moozhe i did, but than it rotates around the upper left point of the canvas instead of the origin of the image (i am setting rendertransformorigin to 0.5,0.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a UserControl to wrap the Thumb since it should be able to act as the root element here.  Here is a solution that involes scrapping the use of TranslateTransform and instead using Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties:

**EDIT: Updated Answer**

Here's the XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Thumb Name="myRoot"
            Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"
            DragDelta="myRoot_DragDelta"
            MouseMove="myRoot_MouseMove"
            MouseDown="myRoot_MouseDown"
            MouseUp="myRoot_MouseUp">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                    <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue"
                               Stroke="#FF0061CE"
                               StrokeThickness="1"
                               Width="100" Height="100"/>
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" />
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
</Canvas>
```

And here's the code behind:

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Point? lastPosition = null;
    RotateTransform rotateTransform;

    private void myRoot_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        lastPosition = null;

        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
            myRoot.CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void myRoot_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
            myRoot.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    private void myRoot_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Point curPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(myRoot);

            if (lastPosition != null)
            {
                Point centerPoint = new Point(myRoot.ActualWidth / 2, myRoot.ActualWidth / 2);

                if (rotateTransform == null)
                    rotateTransform = (RotateTransform)myRoot.Template.FindName("rotateTransform", myRoot);

                rotateTransform.Angle = Math.Atan2(curPosition.Y - centerPoint.Y, curPosition.X - centerPoint.X) * 100;
            }

            lastPosition = curPosition;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void myRoot_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(myRoot, Canvas.GetLeft(myRoot) + e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(myRoot, Canvas.GetTop(myRoot) + e.VerticalChange);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked although the rotation part seemed a bit sluggish, at least at my machine it didnt work out as smooth as i hoped.

Comment: It's not the ideal way to do it.  I'll see if I can write an example of a better way.

Comment: also i see the same strange behavior that i see with my version. Once rotated at more than 90 degrees it starts to behave weird when dragged again (reproduce: drag to middle, rotate 180 degress, than drag in any direction)

Comment: I figured it out.  The Thumb does not report proper delta values when it's transformed.  The Thumb should be higher than the transform in the visual tree (it's content can be transformed).  I'll post my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the RotateTransform that you want to rotate around the center of the object rather than the center of the coordinate system, which is the default. To do that, set the CenterX and CenterY properties of the RotateTransform to the center of the object.

Comment: I thought i did that by setting RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" on the UserControl?